Excel VBA Error with user access Permission.Add
I wrote the following Excel macro to assign user permissions to Excel files.
Sub Add_Permission() 
 
Dim objUserPerm As Office.UserPermission 
Set objUserPerm = ActiveWorkbook.Permission.Add("test@test.com", msoPermissionChange) 
  
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 
  
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ 
        "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\" + "order_id_1" + "output_file.xlsx" _ 
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False 
         
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.EnableEvents = True 
 
End Sub

I have run this macro for months without any issue with a university Office account. Recently, I purchased a Microsoft 365 Business Premium license for a new account. I am the only user in the organization.
After logging into Excel with that, I am not able to run the macro anymore. On execution it gives the following error:
Run-time error '-2147023727 (80070491)':
Method 'Add' of object 'Permission' failed
I do not believe the issue is with VBA code since the macro was/is working with another authenticated account. I believe this might be related to some kind of Azure Rights Management settings or similar. I am not familiar with the Azure Information Protection tools, I simply need to allow the macro execution.
Any lead on how I could solve this?
I have tried to set up Information Protection Sensitivity Labels and Policies multiple times but still the same issue.
I have read multiple times the Microsoft documentation but it's extremely difficult to understand and could not find any solution to my problem.
I am having doubts my Office license is not enough and I might have to purchase an E3 or E5 but by comparing the plans it does not seem to be the case.

Same issue is addressed here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vba-error-with-user-access-permissionadd/7e6bb582-7ffa-4987-a64b-eff4a61cf781

It's me also there, unfortunately it didn't help solving the issue
